# Hibernate OneToOne adding prefix to column

Tags: hibernate

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

I´m a Java Programmer, but I don´t have enough background to work with Hibernate. Since at the office we are trying to learn a few new tecnhologies, I´m trying to use Hibernate to assist us at database issues.

I have two classes, one called Processamento and another called Fila

The table processamento has one registry at Fila, defined by fila.id

**Processamento class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ra_fila_processamento", schema = "processamento")
public class Processamento implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int idProcessamento;
    private int idFila;
    private int idServidor;

    private Fila fila;

    @Column(name="rfp_id")
    public int getIdProcessamento() {
        return idProcessamento;
    }

    public void setIdProcessamento(int idProcessamento) {
        this.idProcessamento = idProcessamento;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="rfp_rf_id")
    public int getIdFila() {
        return idFila;
    }

    public void setIdFila(int idFila) {
        this.idFila = idFila;
    }

    @Column(name="rfp_ser_id")
    public int getIdServidor() {
        return idServidor;
    }

    public void setIdServidor(int idServidor) {
        this.idServidor = idServidor;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="ra_fila", schema="processamento", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="rf_id", unique = true)})
    public Fila getFila() {
        return fila;
    }

    public void setFila(Fila fila) {
        this.fila = fila;
    }

}
```

**Fila class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ra_fila", schema="processamento")
public class Fila implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Fila() {}

    private int idFila;
    private String arquivoFonte;
    private String status;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rf_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getIdFila() {
        return idFila;
    }

    public void setIdFila(int idFila) {
        this.idFila = idFila;
    }

    @Column(name="rf_arquivo_fonte")
    public String getArquivoFonte() {
        return arquivoFonte;
    }

    public void setArquivoFonte(String arquivoFonte) {
        this.arquivoFonte = arquivoFonte;
    }

    @Column(name="rf_status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

The problem is, when I run this code:

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    try {

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Processamento");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Fila> fila = query.list();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        if (fila.size() == 0) return false;

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
}
```

The HQL that is created is this one:

```
select processame0_.rfp_rf_id as rfp1_3_, processame0_.rfp_id as rfp2_3_, processame0_.rfp_ser_id as rfp3_3_, processame0_1_.fila_rf_id as fila4_2_ from processamento.ra_fila_processamento processame0_ left outer join processamento.ra_fila processame0_1_ on processame0_.rfp_rf_id=processame0_1_.rf_id
```

The error in this HQL is this part:

```
processame0_1_.fila_rf_id as fila4_2_
```

This **fila_** should not be there, how can I do this relation OneToOne correctly? I just want to Fetch the column Processamento and get it´s Fila. Processamento has just one result at Fila.

Thanks.

Best regard´s.

[SOLVED]

The main error was that I should not be using JoinTable, JoinTable is like a union clause, I think. Removingo the JoinTable and adding the clause JoinColumn solved my issue, and the select could trigger another select and make the relations exists.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote query for Processamento and fetching `List<Fila>` this is not ok.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Processamento");
List<Processamento> processamentos = query.list();

for(Processamento processamento: processamentos){
   System.out.println(processamento.getFila().getIdFila();
}
```

Comment: Great, fixed it, but I steal have the issue related to the column with the wrong name. Maybe the relations are set wrong or the query? Thanks